# JSF 2.0 - set javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD on a specific manage bean only

Tags: jsf-2

In the web.xml, I've the following:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
   <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This setting effects all jsf managed beans in my app.  I've one particular bean that I want the state to be client.  Is there a way to have only this one bean with set with client as STATE_SAVING_METHOD and the rest with server?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer to your question is 'no'.  It was considered as a feature but ultimately was not implemented.

See: [JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1056](https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1056)