# jsf override default javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD for concrete view

Tags: jsf, web.xml, mojarra

javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD parameter in web.xml is used to specify where the state should be saved. client or server

If you want to save the state on the server (which is the default in the JavaServer Faces reference implementation), specify the param-value value as server.

Otherwise to save the state on the client side we can specify client in the param-value.

If the state is saved on the client, the state of the entire view is rendered to a hidden field on the page.

is there a way to override default global config in web.xml and set a custom state saving strategy for a concrete view?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. See https://github.com/javaee/javaserverfaces-spec/issues/1056

I found this 'answer' in [JSF 2.0 - set javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD on a specific manage bean only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427865/jsf-2-0-set-javax-faces-state-saving-method-on-a-specific-manage-bean-only), but since that Q was about a specific bean and not a view, I'll add this additional answer instead of marking as a duplicate.